# Is there an easy way of hosting a Discord .Net Bot in Heroku?

Tags: .net, heroku, discord, hosting

I tried searching everywhere including the docs, can anyone step by step guide me on how to host my Discord Bot on heroku? Of cource I have all the setup and it does compile. But after that I am blinded on what to do. I get this error (and idk what procfile to use for my (without ASP) .Net Core application)

Update #1:

Okay, so I did some stuff and [this is how far I am](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck8PZ.png)

The main error stopping me from the final steps of enjoying the hosting is this:
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Comment: you can use docker

Comment: I am surprise that there is still nothing happening in heroku to support .net core as platform like java/python/node e.t.c .net core is moving forward day by day and it will be a big opportunity to get .net core developer to use heroku instead of Azure for deployment

Comment: [Nohtaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15227262) wrote an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66240876) saying "Change your process type to worker"